# Toggle filter list with Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, api, filter, axios, material-ui

I'm trying to filter trough my response data using Axios and ReactJS.

I've used Material-UI for their [selection controls](https://material-ui.com/demos/selection-controls) to toggle the filters.

Using the event handler to pass different data into Axios and reloading the current data.

I'm trying to have multiple filter possibilities, example:

Filter option A, B & C

Toggle filter options A: display filter A

With toggle filter A still on true and I hit toggle filter B: display filter A&B

I hope I explained it well enough. I want to be able to filter multiple parameters at the same time.

My code is a bit sloppy cause this is quite new to me. As I've created the same function twice and ideally I would be able to filter trough multiple value's with one function and get the parameter trough the selected toggle, but I fist want to get the filtering to work.

I've tried multiple variations of my current code. Trying to change the filter value's of filter1 or filter2

**Constructor, mounting of the data, event-handler**

```
    super(props);
    const { classes } = props;
    const { products, images } = this.props;
    const filteredproducts = '' ;
    this.state = {
      productsData: {},
      isLoading: true,
      error: null,
      products,
      images,
      classes,
      filteredproducts : products,
      expanded: null,
      gilad: false,
      jason: false,
      include: '?include=images',
      url: 'https://stern-telecom-react-salman15.c9users.io/api/v2/storefront/products',
      filter1: '',
      filter2: '',

    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    axios.get(this.state.url + this.state.include)
      .then(result => this.setState({
        productsData: result.data,
        filteredproducts: result.data.data,
        images: result.data.included,
        isLoading: false,
      }))
      .catch(error => this.setState({
        error,
        isLoading: false
      }));
    if ( this.state.isloading == false) {
      nouislider.create(this.refs.slider2, {
        start: [0, 100],
        connect: [false, true, false],
        step: 1,
          range: { 
            min: 0, 
            max: 100 
          }
      });
    }
  }


  handleChange = panel => (event, expanded) => {
    this.setState({
      expanded: expanded ? panel : false,
    });
  };

  handleFormChange1 = name => event => {

    if( event.target.checked != true ) {

    this.setState({ 
      isLoading: true, 
      [name]: '',
       filter1: 'filter[taxons]=1',
    });
    axios.get( this.state.url + this.state.include + '&'+ this.state.filter1 + '&'+ this.state.filter2)
      .then(result => this.setState({
        productsData: result.data,
        filteredproducts: result.data.data,
        images: result.data.included,
        isLoading: false,
      }))
      .catch(error => this.setState({
        error,
        isLoading: false
      }));
       console.log('true',event.target.checked, this.state.url + this.state.include + '&'+ this.state.filter1 + '&'+ this.state.filter2)
    }
    else {
      this.setState({ 
        isLoading: true, 
        [name]: event.target.checked,
       filter1: '',

      });
      axios.get(this.state.url + this.state.include + '&'+ this.state.filter1 + '&'+ this.state.filter2)
        .then(result => this.setState({
          productsData: result.data,
          filteredproducts: result.data.data,
          images: result.data.included,
          isLoading: false,
        }))
        .catch(error => this.setState({
          error,
          isLoading: false
        }));
        console.log('false', event.target.checked, this.state.url + this.state.include + '&'+ this.state.filter1 + '&'+ this.state.filter2)
    }
  };


handleFormChange2 = name => event => {
    if( event.target.checked != true ) {
    this.setState({ 
      isLoading: true, 
      [name]: '',
      filter2: 'filter[taxons]=3',
    });


    axios.get(this.state.url + this.state.include + '&'+ this.state.filter1 + '&'+ this.state.filter2)
      .then(result => this.setState({
        productsData: result.data,
        filteredproducts: result.data.data,
        images: result.data.included,
        isLoading: false,
      }))
      .catch(error => this.setState({
        error,
        isLoading: false
      }));
       console.log('true',[name],event.target.checked, this.state.API2 )
    }
    else {
      this.setState({ 
        isLoading: true, 
        [name]: event.target.checked,
        filter2: '',
      });

      axios.get(this.state.url + this.state.include + '&'+ this.state.filter1 + '&'+ this.state.filter2)
        .then(result => this.setState({
          productsData: result.data,
          filteredproducts: result.data.data,
          images: result.data.included,
          isLoading: false,
        }))
        .catch(error => this.setState({
          error,
          isLoading: false
        }));
        console.log('false', [name], event.target.checked, this.state.API2)
    }
    console.log(event.target.checked)
  };
```

**User interaction**

```
              <ExpansionPanel defaultExpanded={true}>
                <ExpansionPanelSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}>
                  <Typography className={this.state.classes.heading}>Model</Typography>
                  <Typography className={this.state.classes.secondaryHeading}>Redmi, Go, Mi, Pro</Typography>
                </ExpansionPanelSummary>
                <ExpansionPanelDetails>
                 <FormControl component="fieldset">
                  <FormLabel component="legend">Assign responsibility</FormLabel>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <FormControlLabel
                      control={
                        <Switch
                          checked={this.state.gilad}
                          onChange={this.handleFormChange1('gilad')}
                          value="gilad"
                        />
                      }
                      label="Mi"
                    />
                    <FormControlLabel
                      control={
                        <Switch
                          checked={this.state.jason}
                          onChange={this.handleFormChange2('jason')}
                          value="jason"
                        />
                      }
                      label="Redmi"
                    />
                    <FormControlLabel
                      control={
                        <Switch
                          checked={this.state.antoine}
                          onChange={this.handleFormChange3('antoine')}
                          value="antoine"
                        />
                      }
                      label="Go"
                    />
                  </FormGroup>
                  <FormHelperText>Be careful</FormHelperText>
                </FormControl>
                </ExpansionPanelDetails>
              </ExpansionPanel>
```

What I'm expecting is that when I toggle multiple filter options I get a data feed that actually displays the filtered data (Filter option A and Filter option B)

So when I execute `handleFormChange1` for example I set the state of `filter1` to `=taxon`

and when I execute `handleFormChange2` the state of filter2 to a different taxon

What happens now is that if I give filter1 a value and then toggle filter2, filter1's value is emptied again.

**UPDATE! GOT FILTERS TO WORK BUT...**

I've managed to simplify my code and am able to toggle filters, but it's still buggy. What I mean is that I have to hit the toggle twice before the changes are in effect.

As you can see in the code below, when the `handleFormChange` function is executed it changes the state for the filters if it's respective toggle is set to `true`

But what happens when I press toggle the first time is that my productlist get updated with before the respective filter is changed. So I have to press the same toggle a second time before it loads the change.

I expect to press the toggle button once and the filter value gets changed and then the `productslist` gets refreshed

What happens I have to press the toggle button multiple times before the filter value changes get's passed on.

```
  handleFormChange = name => event => {
    //Change filter's value when the button's value has changed to true or false
    this.setState({ 
      isLoading: true, 
      [name]: event.target.checked,
      filter1: this.state.mi === true ? "1," : '',
      filter2: this.state.redmi === true ? "3," : '',
      filter3: this.state.go === true ? "4,": '',

    });
    //Check if the filter is changed
    console.log('filtersSet', this.state.filter1, this.state.filter2, this.state.filter3)
    //Get new data request from API with new filter value's
      axios.get(this.state.url + this.state.include + '&'+ this.state.taxons + this.state.filter1 + this.state.filter2+ this.state.filter3 + this.state.filter4 + this.state.filter5 + this.state.filter6)
        .then(result => this.setState({
          productsData: result.data,
          filteredproducts: result.data.data,
          images: result.data.included,
          isLoading: false,
        }))
        .catch(error => this.setState({
          error,
          isLoading: false
        }));
        //check the value passed on, the value of the event target and if the state has been changed. 
       console.log(name,event.target.checked, this.state.filter1 , this.state.filter2, this.state.filter3, this.state.mi , this.state.redmi, this.state.go)
  };
```

```
<React.Fragment>
        <div className={this.state.classes.root}>
          <GridContainer>
            <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={3} className={this.state.classes.marginAuto}>
              <ExpansionPanel defaultExpanded={true}>
                  <ExpansionPanelSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}>
                    <Typography className={this.state.classes.heading}>Model</Typography>
                    <Typography className={this.state.classes.secondaryHeading}>Redmi, Go, Mi, Pro</Typography>
                  </ExpansionPanelSummary>
                  <ExpansionPanelDetails>
                   <FormControl component="fieldset">
                    <FormLabel component="legend">Assign responsibility</FormLabel>
                    <FormGroup>
                      <FormControlLabel
                        control={
                          <Switch
                            checked={this.state.mi}
                            onChange={this.handleFormChange('mi')}
                            value="1,"
                          />
                        }
                        label="Mi"
                      />
                      <FormControlLabel
                        control={
                          <Switch
                            checked={this.state.redmi}
                            onChange={this.handleFormChange('redmi')}
                            value="3,"
                          />
                        }
                        label="Redmi"
                      />
                      <FormControlLabel
                        control={
                          <Switch
                            checked={this.state.go}
                            onChange={this.handleFormChange('go')}
                            value="4,"
                          />
                        }
                        label="Go"
                      />
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormHelperText>Be careful</FormHelperText>
                  </FormControl>
                  </ExpansionPanelDetails>
                </ExpansionPanel>

                <ExpansionPanel defaultExpanded={true}>
                  <ExpansionPanelSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}>
                    <Typography className={this.state.classes.heading}>Advanced settings</Typography>
                    <Typography className={this.state.classes.secondaryHeading}>
                      Filtering has been entirely disabled for whole web server
                    </Typography>
                  </ExpansionPanelSummary>
                  <ExpansionPanelDetails>
                    <div className={this.state.classes.sliderContainer}>
                      <div className="slider-info noUi-active" ref="slider2"  />
                    </div>
                  </ExpansionPanelDetails>
                </ExpansionPanel>

                <ExpansionPanel defaultExpanded={true}>
                  <ExpansionPanelSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}>
                    <Typography className={this.state.classes.heading}>Users</Typography>
                    <Typography className={this.state.classes.secondaryHeading}>
                      You are currently not an owner
                    </Typography>
                  </ExpansionPanelSummary>
                  <ExpansionPanelDetails>
                     <FormControl component="fieldset">
                    <FormLabel component="legend">Assign responsibility</FormLabel>
                    <FormGroup>
                      <FormControlLabel
                        control={
                          <Switch
                            checked={this.state.gilad1}
                            onChange={this.handleFormChange('gilad1')}
                            value="gilad"
                          />
                        }
                        label="32GB"
                      />
                      <FormControlLabel
                        control={
                          <Switch
                            checked={this.state.jason1}
                            onChange={this.handleFormChange('jason1')}
                            value="jason"
                          />
                        }
                        label="64GB"
                      />
                      <FormControlLabel
                        control={
                          <Switch
                            checked={this.state.antoine1}
                            onChange={this.handleFormChange('antoine1')}
                            value="antoine"
                          />
                        }
                        label="126GB"
                      />
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormHelperText>Be careful</FormHelperText>
                  </FormControl>
                  </ExpansionPanelDetails>
                </ExpansionPanel>
            </GridItem>
          {
             (error) ? (
                <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={9} className={this.state.classes.productContainer}> 
                  <p>{error.message}</p>
                </GridItem> 
            ): (isLoading) ?  (
                  <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={9} className={this.state.classes.productContainer}> 
                      <Loading/>
                  </GridItem>
            ): (isLoading) == false ? (
              <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={9} className={this.state.classes.productContainer}> 
                <GridList cellHeight={180}  cols={4} className={this.state.classes.gridList}>
                  {filteredproducts.map(product =>
                  <GridListTile className={this.state.classes.card}  rows={1} key={product.id}>
                    <Card  rows={1} className={this.state.classes.center}>
                      <CardHeader color="warning">
                        {product.attributes.name}
                      </CardHeader>
                      <CardBody>
                        {product.relationships.images.data.length > 0 &&
                            (() => {
                              const { id } = product.relationships.images.data[0];
                              const image = images.find(image => image.id == id);
                              return image ? (
                                    <img key={images.key} src={`${url}/${image.attributes.styles[2].url}`} />
                              ) : null;
                            })()}
                        <h4 className={this.state.classes.cardTitle}>
                          {product.attributes.display_price}
                        </h4>
                        <Button color="primary" href={url + productUrl + product.attributes.slug }>
                            View
                        </Button>
                      </CardBody>
                    </Card>
                  </GridListTile>
                  )}
                </GridList>
              </GridItem>
            ) : (isLoading)
          }
        </GridContainer>
      </div> 
    </React.Fragment>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it by adding a `let` outside of my react class and changing it's value with the function if certain parameters where met.

```
  handleFormChange1 = name => event => {

    //Change filter's value when the button's value has changed to true or false
    this.setState({ 
      isLoading: true, 
      [name]: event.target.checked,
    });

    let miTrue = [name] == "mi" ? event.target.checked : false; 

    filter1 = miTrue === true ? "1," : '';

    console.log('fase 1', 'true', miTrue ,'filter', filter1 ,filter2 , filter3, filter4 ,filter5 , filter6, filter7 ,filter8 , filter9, filter10 ,filter11 , filter12   )
    //refresh the productlist
    this.refreshList();

  };

  refreshList(){

    //Get new data request from API with new filter value's
    axios.get(this.state.url + this.state.include + '&'+ this.state.taxons + filter1 + filter2 + filter3 + filter4 + filter5 + filter6)
    .then(result => this.setState({
      productsData: result.data,
      filteredproducts: result.data.data,
      images: result.data.included,
      isLoading: false,
    }))
    .catch(error => this.setState({
      error,
      isLoading: false
    }));
    //check the value passed on, the value of the event target and if the state has been changed. 
    console.log('fase 3',this.state.mi,this.state.redmi, this.state.go )
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you use something like have an array of filter conditions and when you handleChange add the filter condition (taxon name) to your filter conditions array ( you could have it as part of your state)

Then use

```
let filtered = arr.filter(({taxon})=> {
    return taxon === filterConditions.some(element => element === taxon);
});
```

So you test if the taxon matches any of the taxon names in you filterConditions array 
I hope that helps as a pointer to solve the issue

Comment: Thank you, I'll try something out like this. Will test it out tomorrow, and get back to you!

Comment: I've updated my question even though your answer did not solve my problem. Maybe the updates question is